# What is three commas syntax in Go?

Tags: go

Can anyone explain to me what is this line doing? I've never seen this before, I guess.

```
np.Point, np.Valid = Point{}, false
```

As stated in this github [code](https://github.com/dewski/spatial/blob/master/point.go#L65)

Comment: It is just assigning two values in a single line.

Comment: Paste the code here, don't just link to an external site. Also, when linking to GitHub, press Y to get a permalink.  Otherwise, when the code changes, your link no longer points to the right line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a three comma syntax. It is actually initializing two variables together in a line

```
np.Point, np.Valid = Point{}, false
```

is similar to

```
np.Point = Point{}
np.Valid = false
```

Comment: ALERT: `np.Point, np.Valid = Point{}, false` is NOT a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). It is a [tuple assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments).

Comment: The downvote rule is "This answer is not useful" Wrong answers are not useful.

Comment: I agree there is more to add but my answer is that OP get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)
>
> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued
>   operation to a list of variables. There are two forms. In the first,
>   the right hand operand is a single multi-valued expression such as a
>   function call, a channel or map operation, or a type assertion. The
>   number of operands on the left hand side must match the number of
>   values. For instance, if f is a function returning two values,
>
> `x, y = f()`
>
> assigns the first value to x and the second to y. In the second form,
>   the number of operands on the left must equal the number of
>   expressions on the right, each of which must be single-valued, and the
>   nth expression on the right is assigned to the nth operand on the
>   left:
>
> `one, two, three = '一', '二', '三'`

---

A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued
operation to a list of variables. In the second form, the number of operands on the left must equal the number of > expressions on the right, each of which must be single-valued, and the nth expression on the right is assigned to the nth operand on the left.

In your example,

```
np.Point, np.Valid = Point{}, false
```

Or, equivalently,

```
t1 := Point{}
t2 := false
np.Point = t1
np.Valid = t2
```